# Is there a mood difference between the two singular imperative forms?

Tags: imperative

In German the additional -e is optional in the singular imperative, say: *probier!* vs. *probiere!*

Is there a full-on mood difference here or is it just a small matter of taste and nuance?

Answer (score 2):

I can't think of anyone using *Probier**e**!* as a command. It's too short to make it sound soft. The longer the phrase is, and the softer the tone is, the more likely someone uses the -e form.

> Probier was anderes! *(harsh speech)*
>
> Probier**e** was anderes. *(soft speech)*

Adding a particle changes the mood far better:

> Probier **doch** was anderes. *(most likely: soft speech)*

Comment: Probier mal! - Beim Kochen.

Comment: *Probiere mal.* is also possible but should be accompanied by a soft tone.